# Why STATIC attribute for some parameters in java class?

Tags: android

I know what a static variable in java and I know when to use it. But I see often appear in the android source code, the parameter `private static final String TAG = "MyActivity"` Do we really need this variable is kept in memory? I want to know why we use it in this way?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html. Check the topic under prefer static over virtual

Comment: That particular variable is used in combination with Logcat. example: `Log.w(TAG, e.message())`

Comment: Also check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html. This should help you.

Comment: a bit of overhead of an hardcode string, but the code readability and Maintainability improves

Comment: @blackbelt `code readability and Maintainability improves` Agreed but Why there is a overhead ?

Comment: you need to access the variable.

Comment: @blackbelt Accessing variable is much simpler then write the same many times and it also ensure correctness of the constant

Comment: still it has to be accessed at runtime

Comment: @ all: Ok, Thanks, But I think it is mainly for performance reasons for Log, because I think there is no interest that a variable is both static and private in this case.